# How to compile an index.kit file to index.html in VSCode?

Tags: html

How to compile an index.kit file to index.html in VSCode? The Kit format, like Scss, allows you to combine several files into one. Only if scss joins in a css file, then kit joins in html

Answer (score 0):

A *.kit file is just HTML with special comments. You can simply rename index.kit to index.html, but if there is any functionality of KIT, it won't be interpreted (any imports of other HTMLs for example)

If you have imports, simply replace the import line of that specific HTML by copying and pasting the content of that file.

Comment: The kit format will allow me to collect and change large chunks of html code by writing one line. If you know how to do this in an html file and a VSCode program, please write.

Comment: That is not possible with base HTML, that's the reason of KIT to exist.